# Unable to visualize Swagger UI in deployed container

Tags: asp.net, docker, swagger

I containerized a .NET webapi service including swagger and swagger UI. dotnet run runs the app correctly but when I containerized it I became unable to visualize the UI

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DataHandlerAPI.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DataHandlerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DataHandlerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DataHandlerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataHandlerAPI.dll"]
```

what should I change to make it run correctly as with `dotnet run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding these 2 lines line to my dockerfile

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment to 'Development', since Swagger - by default - only is available in development. Containers run in 'Production' environment by default.

You can set it like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal AS base
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DataHandlerAPI.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DataHandlerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DataHandlerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DataHandlerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataHandlerAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, although it works with dotnet run and the env you added is the same as set in lanchSettings.json

Comment: launchsettings.json isn't used at all when you run in a container, so don't be confused by that. It's only used when you run from Visual Studio or another IDE that supports it.

Comment: I know, the problem is not with the launchSettings because it works but with visualizing Swagger UI via the containerized app.